# Curls not showing in render

Tags: rendering, hair

I downloaded Blender yesterday and had a bit of fun sculpting. I was trying to add curly hair to my model and it seems to be working in the display but not in the render (see images). 
What am I missing?

Thanks! Oli

[image: Render settings]
[image: Render settings]
[image: Renders settings]
[image: Curls working in display]
[image: render settings]
[image: render]

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your render strand steps (currently 3, under the render heading in particle settings) match your viewport settings (currently 7, under Display in particle settings). With curly hair you may need quite a few steps to capture all the bends.

You may also need to adjust the scaling value under Cycles Hair Settings if you want the strands to be thinner.